# How to split page like frames in LightSwitch 2013?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm building a program in LightSwitch 2013 on Visual Studio 2013.
I want to create a page the can divide the screen to 2 separate sections (like frameset\iframe:
1. A const web that has const values.
2. Navagaion between pages (ex. http://www.echoecho.com/htmlframes08.htm).

How do i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to divide the screen up with the use of the columns/rows, for example this setup would create this screen layout: I have 3 rows here which each have a weight, by changing this, you can split the screen up. in my example here the left bar where the buttons are is left as (1), I have set the divider inbetween as (0.1) so that there is a distinct line between both frames, and the right/main window is set at (4)

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps

also its worth looking at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiWaJnPhFMw

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3247/Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-HTML-Client-Push-Menu.aspx

it has simple instructions to help you implement it in